# gradle build : use a variable for artifact name

Tags: gradle, build, artifactory

I am working on creating a gradle build which builds a couple of sub projects and then publishes them to the artifactory. 
For publishing the artifacts I need to use a variable name as the artifact name. It's required as the artifact's name contains a timestamp denoting the time at which it was built. 
From the logs I can see that the actual publishing happens after the build for sub projects is done but looks like the variable that I am using for the artifact name is getting initialized before hence it's throwing an error. Below is the publishing part:

```
publishing {
    publications {  
        // This publishes fine as it is picking the latest
        tests(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId 'tests'
            artifact ('tests/build/libs/tests.jar')
        }
        // I need to use a variable name for this
        // This looks for a .carb file in the sub project build directory
        carb(MavenPublication) {
            def carbFile = new File('carb/build/carbs').eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
                if(it.name.endsWith('.carb')) {
                    carbFileName = it
                }
            }
            println carbFileName
            artifactId 'carb'
            artifact carbFileName
        }
    }
}
```

For publish target `'carb'` I was expecting `carbFileName` to be populated at the time of publishing but it doesn't. I can see the `println` statement before the publishing begins hence it holds an incorrect value. any suggestions to handle this?

Comment: Is the carb file which needs to be published created by your Gradle build? If so: how? Is the file supposed to be published as-is (i.e., without zipping it, for example)?

Comment: The carb file is created via a sub project(using a plugin) and same is the case with the test jar. I cannot zip the files as there are some dependencies on other projects which are using it in it's current form. I came up with some other solution. I am using artifactoryPublish.dependsOn to call a task which will look into the build directory of carb and copy paste *.carb file and while doing so renames it using current time defined in main project. That way I have the exact file name which I can use as the artifact name.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess I would have suggested something similar. Since you’ve found an answer yourself, maybe it’s worth to add that as an answer to your question for others running into the same issue?